# RabbitMQ, Spring queue no auto-creation

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm making Spring + RabbitMQ application and got problem.
My RabbitConfiguration:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
    @Bean
    public Queue queue1(){
        return new Queue("queue1");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue2(){
        return new Queue("queue2");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue3(){
        return new Queue("queue3");
    }

}
```

Class, that puts new message inside Rabbit:

```
import api.longpoll.bots.model.objects.basic.Message;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.dompurrr.service.UpdateProducer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class UpdateProducerImpl implements UpdateProducer {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public UpdateProducerImpl(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void produce(String rabbitQueue, Message message) {
        log.info("Putted message in queue "+rabbitQueue);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(rabbitQueue, message);
    }
}
```

Using RabbitMQ 3.11.0

application.properties, but it shouldn't break something.

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=...
spring.rabbitmq.password=...
```

I wanted that application would automatically create new queue in rabbitmq if there's no one, wrote code like this, but it doesn't work.
Can i somehow fix this?